# matplotlib color images are not displayed when used in the command prompt (pdb mode)

Tags: python, matplotlib, command-line

When running python code on the command-line, `python test.py`,
matplotlib doesn't show color images but rather display it as gray images.
Any workaround for displaying images when run on the command line?

demo code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2    
img = cv2.imread('color-image.jpg')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show() # shows gray image
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. Do you want to specify the versions, you use?

Answer (score 0):

You do need to tell OpenCV that you're reading a color image, for example with this:

```
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

If you don't use it like that it will load the image grayscale by default.
Please change the subject as this is not Matplotlib error but OpenCV. There are plenty of examples on the OpenCV documentation:
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html

Comment: Not in my 3.4 version of opencv.

Comment: I don't know if you tried but this should be working with the code above. If it's not working then matplotlib is the problem so you need to tell him to use color.

Comment: You have a nice tutorial on how to load an image in this page https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/03/display-matplotlib-rgb-image/

Comment: He is really good when you want some information about OpenCV and Neural network information on the image processing field